# Given, $a_1 = {24}^{1/3} $ and $ a_{n+1} = {({ a_n + 24})^{1/3}} $ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then integer part of $ a_{100}$ is equal to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, logic

Given, $a_1 = {24}^{1/3} $ and $a_{n+1} = {({ a_n + 24})^{1/3}}$ for for any  $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then integer part of $a_{100}$ is equal to?

As far as my solution goes there is no integer part, but the answer says there certainly is one. 
How to proceed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint. Consider the function $f(x)=(x+24)^{1/3}$. Note that $f(3)=3$.
Show that:

i) $a_n< 3$ (i.e. $0<x<3\implies 0<f(x)<3$);

ii) $a_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence (i.e. $0<x<3\implies f(x)>x$).

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: $a_1\approx 2.8844$. If a_n is increasing and always less than $3$ then the integer part of $a_n$ is always $2$ (even if $a_n\to 3$).

Comment: @user371530 Is it clear now? Any further doubt?

Comment: Yes its is.
Thank you very much!